# basic recursion on Java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to get prime factors by recursing but my code does not work.

```java
factors.add(i)+factors(n/i);
```

in this line I get an error that says:

```java
Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'boolean', 'int[]'.
```

`factors{24}` returns `{2, 2, 2, 3}` and `factors(6) returns {2, 3}`.

I'm trying to get my head around recursion, so can someone please help?

```java
public static int[] factors(int n) {
    List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 2;
    if (n<2){
        return null;
    }
    else{
        if(n%i==0){
            factors.add(i)+factors(n/i);
        }
        else{
            i = i+1;
        }

    }
    int [] ints = factors.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    return ints;
}
```

Comment: `factors.add(i)+factors(n/i);` I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, though it is definitely an error.  Could you describe in more detail?  It looks as though you mean to compute the value of `factors( n/i )` and then insert that into the list, but it's super unclear why you would want to do that.

Comment: OK, I think I'm starting to "get" what's going on here.  I think instead of `add()` you want to `addAll()` that is the call to `factors()` might yield more than one factor.  To do that you need to return a `List` not an array, just because arrays don't work that way.

Comment: Did you tried changing the name of the arraylist ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a private helper method to handle the recursion, it is much easier.  In this case you need to supply the starting divisor so it can change thru subsequent recursive calls.  In some cases you can initialize the data structure inside the method.  But since a helper method is being used, just pass that structure as an argument too.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i : new int[]{24,36,99,101}) {
         List<Integer> f = factors(i);
        System.out.println(i + " - " + f);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
24 - [2, 2, 2, 3]
36 - [2, 2, 3, 3]
99 - [3, 3, 11]
101 - [101]
```

The methods.

```
public static List<Integer> factors(int n) {
    return factorit(new ArrayList<>(), n, 2);
}
    
private static List<Integer> factorit(List<Integer> factrs,
        int n, int m) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return factrs;
    }
    // if m divides m, continue with m and n/m
    if (n % m == 0) {
        factrs.add(m);
        return factorit(factrs, n / m, m);
    }
    // otherwise, continue with current n and the next possible factor.
    return factorit(factrs, n, m + 1);
}
```